# usb thumbdrive not mountable

Tags: mount, usb

I have a problem with my USB thumbdrive (can't access it either in windows - no volumes are shown).

`cat /proc/scsi/scsi` shows the following:

```
 Host: scsi8 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor:          Model: USB MEMORY BAR   Rev: 1000
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 00
```

`dmesg` shows the usb drive:

```
[ 1422.720016] usb 2-7: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 1425.004881] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-7:1.0
[ 1426.005127] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1426.005734] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 1426.008739] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

but manually mounting was not successful:

```
 sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdd /mnt/usb
 Failed to mount '/dev/sdd': No medium found
```

Comment: FTR: Closed because the problem "went away on its own" (the USB drive had a hardware fault).

Answer (score 2):

The partition you wish to mount most probably is `/dev/sdd1` (provided the device actually contains a mountable partition).

You can investigate the situation using `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd`

Comment: Hello, it tried it but it was not successful - probably the volume is damaged? In windows disk management I cannot see any volume. Is there a possibility to format the data structure of the thumbrdrive again?

Comment: Could you update the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd` to your question? With fdisk you can create partitions and with `mkfs` the filesystem.

Comment: the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd` is empty. Any idea why? `sudo fdisk -l` shows my internal HDDs correctly, but not my usb thumbdrive.

Comment: Weird. Looks like the /dev/sdd is not there afterall. Does `ls -l /dev/sdd*` list the usb drive?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. the weird about that issue is, that a few minutes ago I copied files to the (new! (2-3 weeks old) stick successfully. Then the status (of the usb thumbdrive) suddenly changed to "device not ready" and since then it was not recognized any more (neither windows nor linux). Because of no visible volumes I cannot re-format the stick.

Comment: You need to find more info from the logs, why the device is being disconnected. Try to look for the reason from the `/var/log/syslog` file. Something must be there after the `[ 1426.008739] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk` entry.

Comment: thread can be closed, the stick looks like its damaged. thank you for your help!